# How can I farm orens?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is there any way to "farm" for orens in *The Witcher 2*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to gain orens continually

- Farming monsters
- Playing dice poker
- Fistfighting
- Arm wrestling

There are certain monsters than respawn, so you can farm them for alchemy and crafting ingredients and sell them. The respawning ends in many cases once you complete the quest for eliminating those monsters.

The three minigames are also a possible source of money, there are usually opponents you can challenge an unlimited amount of times, each time earning money.

Comment: Ugh. Dice Poker is frustrating to try to earn money with; what do you mean full house beats a straight? Gaaah!

Comment: @Raven I skipped dice poker pretty much completely, the fist fights though are easy enough. I didn't find any need to grind for money though, I had always enough for the stuff I needed.

Comment: @Fabian - aye, me too; but I wanted to complete Poker Face, so I had to.

Comment: @Raven & @Fabian: I just save before playing poker and load when I loose :P

Comment: @benregn I just find the dice poker game tedious, it is just not fun for me. BTW, you can't use @ to notify multiple users in comments, the second one is ignored. In this case I was notified because you commented on my answer.

Comment: Right, forgot about that. But at least I remember that the answer owner always gets notified. But I agree with you that the poker is a bit dull, just able to get OK money out of it.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to make money involves the old quarry outside Vergen and harpees. Run all the way to the bottom killing harpees on the way and collecting their body parts as you go. When you are at the bottom and all harpees are dead, walk up the little trail where the treasure chest is and wait a few hours. The harpees will have re-spawned when you leave the meditation screen. Do the same on the way up and out of the quarry. Go past the shack and wait again and they will re-spawn again. You can do this an unlimited number of times. If you start this with nothing in your inventory but your armor and swords you can gather enough harpee parts to earn yourself around 3,000 dollars when you get heavy enough to have to go sell them all. It doesn't take long to rack up more money than you will need for the rest of the game.

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way was definitely arm wrestling. Make sure you do the quest for arm wrestling, then when you get to the last opponent you can bet 100 orens on him and its super easy to win. Then just keep doing it over and over. 100 Orens every 10 seconds.

Comment: what guy are you talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately the last guy, in chapter 3 you can only arm wrestle once but, beware as the first time time you will lose unless either buy steroids from the vendor standing next to him or you lose once. Call him a cheater and you will fist fight then after beating him, arm wrestle again and bet the max 600 Orens as he will be very very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/faqs/62417) by blue_devil_99 on Gamefaqs:

> By FAR the best farming location in the game is in Chapter 2, in the forests
> outside Vergen near the dwarves catacombs.  This location is reachable almost
> immediately on Iorveth's path.  For Roche's path you reach this location much
> later in the chapter.
>
> In one corner of this forest there is a pool where a small army of Nekkers
> spawn.  If you're farming mutagens, these Nekkers can drop ALL mutagens in the
> game, including the ultra-rare Madness mutagen.  If you're farming orens, they
> drop Nekker teeth that sell for 4 orens each, along with hearts, eyes, and
> claws that sell for 2.  You'll get several hundred of each very quickly.  The
> key in both cases is that 20 or so spawn at once, so you have LOTS of chances,
> and you can kill them extremely quickly with Grapeshot bombs.
>
> The only tricky thing is how to reset the encounter.  This encounter will only
> happen once, possibly twice, unless you follow a very specific sequence:
>
> 1. Begin just after midnight.  If it's not, meditate until midnight and run
>    around killing stuff for a minute or two.
> 2. Walk to the exact center of the path across the river (after entering the
>    area, make right at the water; the path is just ahead on your left and leads
>    to a glade where you encounter 4 harpies).
> 3. Meditate until midnight of the next day (almost the full 24 hours).
> 4. Save and reload the game.  Kill the Nekkers, loot, and go back to step 1.
>
> Repeat the process until you're overloaded, then go sell all those Nekker
> parts in Vergen.  If you're farming mutagens you can just drop all the Nekker
> parts and they will disappear when you reload.  There is really no reason
> to farm much more than the 10k orens you need for the Steam achievement.
>
> Unless you're on Roche's path and want to stock up on runes or rune diagrams,
> there's really not much point farming in Chapter 1.  If you really want to,
> it's probably possible to force the Nekkers in the caves in Chapter 1 to
> respawn using a method similar to the one I describe above.

Other alternatives are to cheat or to use a mod that makes NPCs [bet more in dice poker](https://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/706), possibly coupled with [another mod that makes you always win](https://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/646?tab=files).